# OpenXml Convert from Word document to HTML with Header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I want to read a .docx file and send its content in Email as email body not as an attachment.

So for this I use openXML and OpenXmlPowerTools to convert docx file to html. This is almost working fine until i got a document which has **Header** and **Footer** with images.

Here is my code to convert .docx to Html

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
                {
                    HtmlConverterSettings convSettings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
                    {
                        FabricateCssClasses = true,
                        CssClassPrefix = "cls-",
                        RestrictToSupportedLanguages = false,
                        RestrictToSupportedNumberingFormats = false,
                        ImageHandler = imageInfo =>
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo localDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(imageDirectoryName);
                            if (!localDirInfo.Exists)
                            {
                                localDirInfo.Create();
                            }

                            ++imageCounter;
                            string extension = imageInfo.ContentType.Split('/')[1].ToLower();
                            ImageFormat imageFormat = null;
                            if (extension == "png")
                            {
                                extension = "jpeg";
                                imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                            }
                            else if (extension == "bmp")
                            {
                                imageFormat = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                            }
                            else if (extension == "jpeg")
                            {
                                imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                            }
                            else if (extension == "tiff")
                            {
                                imageFormat = ImageFormat.Tiff;
                            }

                            // If the image format is not one that you expect, ignore it,
                            // and do not return markup for the link.
                            if (imageFormat == null)
                            {
                                return null;
                            }

                            string imageFileName = imageDirectoryName + "/image" + imageCounter.ToString() + "." + extension;

                            try
                            {
                                imageInfo.Bitmap.Save(imageFileName, imageFormat);
                            }
                            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
                            {
                                return null;
                            }

                            XElement img = new XElement(Xhtml.img, new XAttribute(NoNamespace.src, imageFileName), imageInfo.ImgStyleAttribute, imageInfo.AltText != null ? new XAttribute(NoNamespace.alt, imageInfo.AltText) : null);
                            return img;
                        }
                    };

                    XElement html = OpenXmlPowerTools.HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc1, convSettings);
```

Above code works fine, convert images as well, but if the document has header and footer those are not converted.

So is their any workaround to include header and footer in html file.

Please suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: (I know this a bit irrelevant) Is there any particular reason why you are using OpenXML SDK instead of MS Word Interop Assembly?

Comment: @AzazulHaq i think MS Word Interop Assembly need MS Office to be installed on your machine, so i avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenXmlPowerTools ignores headers and footers when converting a docx-document to HTML, so they won't show up in the resulting HTML (you can [browse the source code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/blob/vNext/OpenXmlPowerTools/WmlToHtmlConverter.cs) on github).

Perhaps it's because the concept of a 'page' doesn't apply to HTML, so there's no obvious equivalent to a document header.